# Mysql join with three tables are not working like expected

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three different tables, one is products_request table with requested quantity and price , 2nd one is products_header_response with order id details and third one is products_response table as confirmed quantity and price.Now I want to query total requested quantity times price (means total amount of requested products in dollars ) and confirmed quantity times price ( total confirmed products in dollars).  But I am getting wrong amount for some orders and correct amount for some orders.

```
For example correct scenario is total requested quantity values is $200 then confirmed quantity values is also $200 (if we confirm all requested products)
Wrong scenario is requested quantity value is $200 and confirmed quantity values is more than requested quantity value like some $300.
```

Below is my query to join 3 tables.

```
SELECT resp.id,resp.order_number,resp.orderdate,
ROUND(SUM(req.`requested_quantity` * req.`net_price`),2) AS Req_Order_Amnt,
ROUND((SUM(items_resp.dispatch_quantity * items_resp.`net_price`)+ SUM(items_resp.backorder_quantity * items_resp.`net_price`)),2) 
AS Tot_Confirmed_Amnt,
req.edi_order_id,req.requested_quantity
FROM products_header_response resp
JOIN products_request req 
ON req.`edi_order_id` = resp.`order_number`
JOIN products_response items_resp 
ON resp.id= items_resp.`edi_order_response_id` 
WHERE DATE(resp.orderdate) BETWEEN '20180411' AND '20180411'  AND (items_resp.`dispatch_quantity`!='' OR items_resp.`backorder_quantity`!='')
GROUP BY items_resp.`edi_order_response_id`
```

In products_response table confirmed quantity will be sent in two columns ie dispatch_quantity and backorder_quantity . If backorder quantity is there then in backorder_quantity column , if dispatch quantity is there then in dispatch_quantity column or if both quantities are  there, then in both columns quantity will be sent.

```
For example requested quantity 100, then if dispatch quantity is 50 and backorder quantity is 20  then 50, 20 will be sent in respective columns and 30 will be sent as rejected quantity.
```

Below join with two tables are working like expected but from this join I can able to get only confirmed quantity amount.

```
SELECT resp.id,resp.order_number,resp.orderdate,
ROUND((SUM(items_resp.dispatch_quantity * items_resp.`net_price`) + SUM(items_resp.backorder_quantity * items_resp.`net_price`)),2) 
AS Tot_Confirmed_Amnt
FROM product_header_response resp
JOIN products_response items_resp 
ON resp.id= items_resp.`edi_order_response_id` 
WHERE DATE(resp.orderdate) BETWEEN '20180411' AND '20180411'  
AND (items_resp.`dispatch_quantity`!='' OR items_resp.`backorder_quantity`!='')
GROUP BY items_resp.`edi_order_response_id`
```

Please correct me where I am doing wrong with the joins. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
products_respose table
id| order_number
3456 ABC123

Products Request table 
edi_order_id| requested_quantity|net_price|product_id
ABC123           2                26.44    pr123 
ABC123           2                22.29    pr234
ABC123           1                12.34    pr321 
ABC123           2                20.05    pr345
ABC123           1                18.26    pr546
ABC123           2                26.48    pr456
ABC123           2                26.44    pr567
```

Products response table

```
dispatch_quantity|backorder_quantity|net_price | product_id | edi_order_resp_id
-                   -                 26.44         pr123         3456
-                   -                 22.29         pr234         3456
-                   -                 12.34         pr321         3456
2                   -                 20.05         pr345         3456
-                   -                 18.26         pr546         3456
2                   -                 26.48         pr456         3456
-                   -                 26.44         pr567         3456
```

Expected Result should be

```
Order_id | Tot_req_Qty_amount |Tot_confirmed_Qty_amount| Requested_products
ABC123     274.00               93.96                      12
```

But I am getting the below wrong result from the 3 joins

```
Order_id | Tot_req_Qty_amount |Tot_confirmed_Qty_amount| Requested_products
    ABC123     548.00               651.42                      24
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Also, you may wish to help us help you by making your code more readable.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I have edited post, added my desired output and added currently what I am getting as wrong out put. Please check

Comment: try using http://sqlfiddle.com/ - easier to help you if you setup your issue